# linker command failed, sdl

Tags: c++, sdl, clang

I'm trying to compile my very first SDL program, but it doesn't compile.By the way, this shouldn't be about setting up the library I guess because I think that I installed the library properly.

This is my command :

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -framework SDL2
```

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error message :

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Invocation :

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 224.1 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/yunusaydin -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.9.0 -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/ss/mltsqt6n3jn2kv85gmyn060r0000gn/T/main-Ref4XX.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.0 based upon LLVM 3.3svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -o main /var/folders/ss/mltsqt6n3jn2kv85gmyn060r0000gn/T/main-Ref4XX.o -framework SDL2 -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: framework not found SDL2
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help :)

Comment: Should `.` be a `\` in the path to the headers?

Comment: I updated it. What do you think about this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `-v to see invocation`?

Comment: `framework not found SDL2`, you're not linking the SDL library.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. How can I link the SDL library?

Comment: I think it's `g++ (your other stuff here) -l<Library Name>`. In your case, I'm assuming your library name is `SDL`. You should have a `.lib` somewhere for SDL, try using the name of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, this command works :

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```

Comment: Yes this works for me too, but for frameworks stored in `/System/Library/Frameworks` I only need the `-framework` option (e.g. OpenGL). Why?

Comment: wcochran: I'm wondering the same. According to GCC manual that path should be in the default search path already https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Darwin-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

`/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers` probably does not exist on your system.

Comment: Yes you're right. It should have been /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers, so I changed it, but now it says clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: So what do you do if it doesn't exist? I installed SDL2 through brew `brew install sdl2`, yet the SDL2.framework folder does not exist...