# SDL2 headers not being found when compiling os x

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2

I can't seem to compile this program. I have other people in my class that are having no problem compiling this code. I'm using the same command to try to compile the program and installed the frameworks in the same directory as them. /Library/Frameworks. I also installed eclipse and followed the zamma.co.uk tutorial to setup sdl2 and that didn't work either. Here is the command i'm running when compiling

g++ -std=c++11 -o Gravity main.cpp Game.cpp Particle.cpp Point.cpp -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -framework SDL2 -framework Cocoa

Note: I have tried both

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

and

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

and neither work

Comment: When "neither work" what error output are you getting from `g++`?

Comment: for `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` i get `fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found` for `#include <SDL.h>` i get  ld: framework not found SDL2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1 @DrewMacInnis

Comment: Does `find /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework -name "SDL.h"` find that header file? Is it under an SDL2 directory or somewhere else?

Comment: when i run that command i get this `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers/SDL.h`      @DrewMacInnis

Comment: Using `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` should work.  See [this](http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-mac-command-line/) tutorial.  However I don't believe you need the `-I` option; using `-framework` will do that for you.

Comment: Answer this question first and the answer will present itself.  What is the full path to `SDL.h` from where you installed it?

Comment: Did you install SDL using `homebrew`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ld` linker error you mention in your comments suggests you may need to pass the `-F` option or `-L` in case your features/library search path is not finding your SDL2 installation.

Your problem sounds similar to:

- [linker command failed, sdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722476/linker-command-failed-sdl)
- [How do you include files in C++ from the /Library/Framework folder in MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277477/how-do-you-include-files-in-c-from-the-library-framework-folder-in-mac)

Comment: Thank you so much! the first link worked I looked forever never found anything that helped. Thanks again @DrewMacInnis

Comment: You're welcome @o.hdz1, although an answer check mark or up vote would be nice.